# Calculate how many days the stock was at a site with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate how many days the stock for an item has been sitting at a site.

There are two tables: `Stock` table shows the items and stock currently on hand and `Receipts` table show the dates when the site has received stock and quantity.

I want to do a left outer join to see all the items in the Stock table and only the rows from the Receipts table with the date where there is still stock left from.

**Stock**

```
| Item  |Current Stock| Value |
|-------|-------------|-------|
|Blade  |8            |$40    |
|Table  |15           |$100   |
|Screen |3            |$30    |
```

**Receipts**

```
| Item  |Receipt Date| Quantity|
|-------|------------|---------|
|Blade  |1/3/2020    |  20     |
|Blade  |12/10/2021  |  10     |
|Blade  |1/5/2022    |  5      | 
|Table  |3/4/2020    |  10     |
|Table  |5/1/2021    |  7      |
|Table  |7/10/2021   |  5      |
|Table  |8/1/2021    |  5      |
```

Dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format. Assuming the current date here is 2/1/2022.

**Desired Results**

```
| Item  |Current Stock| Value |Receipt Date|Age in Days|
|-------|-------------|-------|------------|-----------|
|Blade  |8            |$40    |12/10/2021  |53         |  
|Table  |15           |$100   |5/1/2021    |276        |
|Screen |3            |$30    |            |           |
```

Logic:

```
| Item  |Receipt Date  | Quantity|Running Sum|Running Sum-Current Stock|
|-------|--------------|---------|-----------|-------------------------|
|Blade  |1/3/2020      |  20     |35         |27                       | 
|Blade  |**12/10/2021**|  10     |15         |7                        |
|Blade  |1/5/2022      |  5      |5          |0                        |
```

For example:
Currently there are 8 units of Blades in stock. The lastest receipt (on 1/5/2022) was 5 units. So there are still 3 units remaining from the 12/10/2021 receipt date. I want to see the first receipt date where the (Running Sum-Current Stock) is greater than 0. This is based on FIFO (First In First Out)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain the logic aso.

Comment: Perhaps you can also add some `yyyymmdd` info to get the difference of for example '12/10/2021' being the 12th day of October or the 10th of December

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention the name of DBMS. My answer is for SQL Server. For other DBMS you need to change `datediff()` function.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Stock(Item    varchar(50), Current_Stock  int, Value int);
 insert into Stock values('Blade'   ,8  ,40);
 insert into Stock values('Table'   ,15 ,100);
 insert into Stock values('Screen'  ,3  ,30);
 
 create table Receipts(Item varchar(50), Receipt_Date date, Quantity int);
 insert into Receipts values('Blade','1/3/2020',    20);
 insert into Receipts values('Blade','12/10/2021',  10);
 insert into Receipts values('Blade','1/5/2022',    5);
 insert into Receipts values('Table','3/4/2020',    10);
 insert into Receipts values('Table','5/1/2021',    7);
 insert into Receipts values('Table','7/10/2021',   5);
 insert into Receipts values('Table','8/1/2021',    5);
```

Query:

```
 with Recepts_with_runningtotal_qty as
 (
    select *, sum(Quantity)over(partition by Item order by Receipt_Date desc) running_total_qty from Receipts
 ),
 current_stock as
 (
    select *, (select max(Receipt_Date) from Recepts_with_runningtotal_qty r where r.running_total_qty>s.current_stock and s.Item=r.Item)Receipt_Date
    from Stock s
 )
 select *,datediff(day, Receipt_Date,'2/1/2022')Age_in_Days from current_stock
```

Output:

| Item | Current_Stock | Value | Receipt_Date | Age_in_Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blade | 8 | 40 | 2021-12-10 | 53 |
| Table | 15 | 100 | 2021-05-01 | 276 |
| Screen | 3 | 30 | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f7953985cc31377e0861a77ddf3874b)*

For Oracle you can use below query:

```
 with Recepts_with_runningtotal_qty as
 (
    select Item , Receipt_Date, Quantity, sum(Quantity)over(partition by Item order by Receipt_Date desc) running_total_qty from Receipts
 ),
 current_stock as
 (
    select Item , Current_Stock, Value, (select max(Receipt_Date) from Recepts_with_runningtotal_qty r where r.running_total_qty>s.current_stock and s.Item=r.Item)Receipt_Date
    from Stock s
 )
 select Item, Current_Stock, Value, Receipt_Date,(to_date('1 Feb 2022','DD MM YY')-Receipt_Date)Age_in_Days from current_stock
```

Output:

| ITEM | CURRENT_STOCK | VALUE | RECEIPT_DATE | AGE_IN_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blade | 8 | 40 | 10-DEC-21 | 53 |
| Table | 15 | 100 | 01-MAY-21 | 276 |
| Screen | 3 | 30 | *null* | *null* |

Query 2: without using common table expression

```
select Item, Current_Stock, Value, Receipt_Date,(to_date('1 Feb 2022','DD MM YY')-Receipt_Date)Age_in_Days
     from
     (
       select Item, Current_Stock, Value, Receipt_Date,Quantity, Running_Total_Qty,
       row_number()over(partition by Item order by Receipt_Date desc)rn
       from
       (
         Select S.Item, S.Current_Stock, S.Value, R.Receipt_date, R.Quantity,
         sum(Quantity)over(partition by R.Item order by Receipt_Date desc) running_total_qty
         From Stock S 
         Left outer join Receipts R On (S.Item = R.Item)
       )
       where Running_Total_Qty>= Current_Stock or Running_Total_Qty is null
     )
     where rn=1
```

Output:

| ITEM | CURRENT_STOCK | VALUE | RECEIPT_DATE | AGE_IN_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blade | 8 | 40 | 10-DEC-21 | 53 |
| Screen | 3 | 30 | *null* | *null* |
| Table | 15 | 100 | 01-MAY-21 | 276 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6064d1bbfeeb8c9dc9244c56ec1621f7)*

Comment: This was very helpful! I'm using Oracle. I'm not fimiliar with the "WITH" clause though. This is how I currently have my query structured. how/where can I add this logic?                                                                                                                                 Select:
 S.Item,
 S.Current_Stock,
 S.Value,
 R.Receipt_date,
 R.Value
From Stock S
Left outer join Receipts R
 On (S.Item = R.Item)

Comment: The first query for Oracle worked! Thank you. However, the query is taking a very long time to execute since there are about 25K rows of data in the Stock table and 170K rows in the Receipts table. Is there any way to fix this issue or improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare variable with your current date, or use GETDATE() -
`DECLARE @Today AS DATE SET @Today = GETDATE`  or some other date if you need.

And then, you can use DATEDIFF, like that:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @Today, Receipt Date) AS date_diff_days
```

After that just perform left outer join it should work fine. Have fun :)